# Centre Image in DIV (Original can be bigger than DIV)

Tags: css, image, html, alignment, center

Struggling with the dreaded centring of different sized images in a DIV.

Got a solution from StackOverflow ( [How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div) ), using a `<SPAN>` as a dummy element (with `vertical-align: middle`) and it works well except for the images which are bigger than the DIV and these are correctly resized, but shown below the DIV.

If I remove the `<SPAN>`, then the centring works in the horizontal, but not in the vertical.

If there is a simple change, I can make as I like the simplicity of the solution.

The tests are at

http://mclportal.net/ModalTests.html

Comment: set it as a background image, then use this css `background-position:center; background-size: contain;`

Comment: do you know the dimensions of the image when they are put onto the page?

Comment: I do not know the size of the images, I was letting the power of the browser resize them for me, if they are bigger than the container.

Comment: @RoyPicko92 an excellent idea, but when the image is larger than the div it just cuts the centre amount it needs from the original image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
<div id="divModal" style="display:table">
   <div id="divImage" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
      <img id="img" src=".........">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works very well. Can not upvote as I have not got a high reputation - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should put max width and max heights on your images.  Then just use relative positioning of the images inside a div with a relative position.  for instance...

```
<div style="height: 300px; width: 300px; position: relative; text-align: center;>
<img src="#" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px; position: relative; top: 50px; />
</div>
```

Using an approach like this all images will be vertically aligned with each other and centered within their div container. Plus having max height and width set will allow the image to keep its aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I do not know the size of the images and I am relying on the browser to resize them to fit within my DIV

Answer (score 0):

@mcl not sure if you've managed to resolve your problem yet.

If not checkout out my blog post [centering large images in smaller containers](http://blog.tom-maton.co.uk/post/68771433738/centering-larger-width-images-each-with-a-different) their is also a codepen demo on there.

I had the same issue and managed to get it working without any need of javascript or inline styles.

Hope it helps